# How to show bar graphs on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, graph

I want to know how to show revenue details in the form of bar graph in iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:

- [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)
- [how to generate graphs using integer values in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023359/how-to-generate-graphs-using-integer-values-in-iphone)
- [Bar Graphs in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164523/bar-graphs-in-ios-app)

To name a few.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [CorePlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), it should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's Charts to display graphs on iPhone and they are very pretty and easy to implement

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/